# Apple Metal Shader Language (MSL) Always Linear Color?

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to understand color within the context of a metal fragment (or compute) shader.

My understanding is that within the context of a metal shader any color values are always linear. Whatever texture is attached to fragment or compute function, metal will apply the inverse of any linear transfer function (gamma) on the way into the shader, and apply it again on the way out.

With this in mind, if within the context of a shader, I return a value with an approximate linear middle grey value of around 22.25%, when rendered to the screen using metal kit via a simple `.bgra8Unorm` texture, I would expect to get a non-linear sRGB reading of around 128,128,128.

```
fragment float4 fragment_shader(
    TextureMappingVertex in [[stage_in]]
) {
    float middleGrey = float(0.2225);
    return float4(middleGrey, middleGrey, middleGrey, 1);
}
```

But in fact I get an output of 57,57,57 which is what I would expect if there were no conversion to and from the linear color space within the shader:

[image: Linear Middle Grey]

What am I missing here?

On the one hand, this certainly seems more intuitive, but it goes against what I thought were the rules for Metal shaders in that they are *always* in linear space.

Comment: What happens when you render into a `.bgra8Unorm_srgb` texture?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel then it renders it as 128,128,128 – which is what I thought it would do originally! I thought values were always linear within the shader?

Comment: In the shader, yes. But what you write into the texture is interpreted differently depending on the format of the texture. The `_srgb` textures will apply the conversion linear -> sRGB when storing the values.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Right, so if I understand correctly, a non-linear to linear transform only occurs if a source texture is _srgb, and a linear to non-linear transform only happens if a destination texture is _srgb.

I'm asking in the context of video: I had always assumed video from an AVCaptureDevice had its inverse transport function applied when delivered as biplanar .r8Unorm and rgUnorm textures and then accessed within the shader – but I guess this means that's not the case? The textures are still gamma compressed even though the shader working space is 'linear'?

Comment: I might be wrong, but if you set the format of your capture output to one of the `420YpCbCr` formats (the default, I think), you get two textures representing your image in the Y'CbCr color space, where Y' means non-linear, gamma-corrected luminance. If you conversion from Y'CbCr to RGB doesn't linearize gamma, you end up with non-linear RGB values, which should be stored in a `_srgb` texture so that Metal knows that these values are gamma-corrected.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel ahh, yes. That may very well be the trick! I'll give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion.